# Zoom with control + plus and control - minus?

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to implement zoom in an application. The user should be able to zoom using `control + plus/minus`.

I would like this to work on

- This should work on Windows, MacOS, Linux
- Different keyboard layouts

This is how I have tried to solve the problem

```
Keys.onPressed: {
    if (event.modifiers & Qt.ControlModifier) {
        var zoomX = event.modifiers & Qt.AltModifier ? false : true

        if (event.key === Qt.Key_Minus) {
            zoom(false, zoomX)
            event.accepted = true
        } else if (event.key === Qt.Key_Plus) {
            zoom(true, zoomX)
            event.accepted = true
        }
    }
}
```

But this does not work well enough.

When I press `shift + equal sign` on a Mac with english keyboard layout, `event.key == 43 && event.key == Qt.Key_Plus`. All good.

But when I press `command + shift + equal sign` on the same keyboard, `event.key == 61 && event.key == Qt.Key_Equal`. In other words the control modifier overrode the shift key and plus is no longer registered and the zoom function is not called.

I tried fixing this by adding the equal sign as an alternative event.key for zoom in. But this does not fix the problem on other keyboard layouts where the plus sign can share a key with some other character.

It feels like I am missing some part of the puzzle. What am I missing? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: it seems that there is some error here - you press Sift '=' and get '+' ? That's not so good. You say you need +/-, but why then there is Key_Equal here?

Comment: Equal sign and plus sign are on the same key on american keyboards. Shift + equal sign makes a plus sign. So no mistake. Let me know if you meant something else and I misunderstood you